Find an arrow in the fragment of an Android mobile application (Android Studio)
I'm currently developing an Android mobile application in Android Studio for a project aimed at creating an app that centralizes mini-games for playing online or locally. My project is progressing well, but I have a rather basic problem that I can't seem to solve. When I created the project in the software, I chose "Bottom Navigation Views Activity" because I wanted to integrate a bottom navigation bar to facilitate navigation. When you create a project from this option, you get 3 fragments linked to 3 pre-made ViewModels. These three fragments are integrated into the navigation bar. For my application, I add a new fragment to the navigation each time for each new mini-game. For example, I added the "TicTacToe" game fragment.
My problem is as follows: when adding a new fragment to the navigation but NOT integrating it into the bottom navigation bar (to access it, I use a specific button directly in a fragment), and in the top bar of the fragment next to the name I defined for the fragment, I have an arrow symbolizing the return to the previous fragment which is completely unusable. I don't know in which XML file (or other) this arrow is defined, so I don't know how to either use it for my application or make it disappear.
Does anyone know how I could access this arrow?
I searched through all the files present, but I can't find this arrow. However, for aesthetic reasons, I would like to be able to use it.


Can you show what arrow you mean?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wb8eMRVG7ZyXqguqrWUqbn24tCaNgGHD/view?usp=drive_link
Keep me posted if you have access to the image.

please edit the question with the image added, I am not gong to click on a third party link

You can get the click of that arrow by watching for the menu item android.R.id.home in onOptionsItemSelected of the activity
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


Thanks you very much ! My application is good now !
